# Intuitive functional analysis book

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, textbook-recommendation

I want to know functional analysis book like Terence tao's real analysis and measure theory book, full of intuition. I am aware of linear algebra, real analysis, measure theory, Probability theory.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you mean by "full of intuition".  Examples?  Heuristics?  As the question stands it looks like you're asking if Terry Tao has written a functional analysis textbook.

Comment: I recently wrote a book on [measure theory and functional analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Measure-Theory-Functional-Analysis-Weaver/dp/981450856X) which I like to think includes a lot of intuition. But probably most authors would say this.

Comment: The nicest  book of functional analysis I can think of is still  the 3 volume  opus **Linear Operators** by  Dunford and Schwartz.   This book  has a tone of examples.    It has  one drawback: it runs 2000 pages long. Still worth consulting. If you do not have the time or  patience to  read  2000 pages, then you should open Haim Brezis book on functional analysis.

Comment: I like Reed & Simon's Methods of Mathematical Physics volume 1: Functional Analysis.  Actually, all 4 volumes are excellent.

Answer (score 7):

The book  A. Ya.  Helemskii, Lectures and exercises on functional analysis. AMS, Providence, RI, 2006 (translation from the Russian original) is IMHO well written and quite intuitive (check e.g. the [MathSciNet review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2248303) which is quite glowing).

Answer (score 3):

Kreyszig is one I found most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'm at the moment enjoying the style of Graham Allan's Introduction to Banach Spaces and Algebras. It's packed with details and is I suppose somewhat dense, but the text is crisply clear and focused. There are also extensive notes. It doesn't assume any measure theory, but a background certainly helps, especially when it comes to the notes.
Here's an MAA review- http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/introduction-to-banach-spaces-and-algebras

I had a little exposure from auditing a Coursera's Functional Analysis offering and a more thorough grounding in measure theory when I came to it, but with a modest overhead of effort you could get into it with less.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that Allan's book apparently has a few issues with some of the exercises (these would no doubt be fixed in any revised edition) See http://matthewdaws.github.io/mathematics/files/ibsa/corrections.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'Beginning Functional Analysis by Karen Saxe' is pretty good. The only downside could be that the book is quite elementary.